# Social network anaylsis

Tags: python, sna

```
social=nx.read_gpickle('Synthetic Social Network (2).pkl')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
nx.draw_networkx(social,node_color="cyan",node_size=700, with_labels=True)
```

I got this:

```
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute '_node'
```

How can I solve the problem?